# Texture splits in the middle

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, geometry-nodes

How can I make the texture line up better? It splits in the middle. I'm using applied geometry nodes.

[image]

You can find the texture [here](https://www.sharetextures.com/textures/floor/fusion_1/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you wrap a flat texture on an object, there will always be seams: the places where the edges of the texture meet each other.  When you have a non-tiling texture like the one you've chosen, the best you can do is *hide* the seams by placing them where they are hidden from the camera view, or at least obscured and less apparent.

In the case of your torus, I would suggest two seams, one around the *inside* of the torus and one in back that cuts the torus in half:

[image: Torus showing seams meant to hide the wrapping]

You add a seam by selecting the edges you want to be part of the seam and then typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>–<kbd>E</kbd> and selecting *Mark Seam* from the drop down menu:

[image: How to mark a seam.]

In this case, since the two sets of edges I would use as seams are edge loops, you can quickly select one by hovering over one of its edges and holding <kbd>Alt</kbd> while left clicking.

Once you have the seams set, you need to rebuild the UV map:

- Select all vertices
- Type <kbd>U</kbd>
- Select *Unwrap* from the menu

Unfortunately, this will not give you a good unwrapping -- it will place the torus in the corner of the UV map.  You'll need to rotate, move, and scale it, until it's centered and mostly fills the map:

[image: Mostly useful UV map]

There are tools you can use for this but that's outside the scope of the question.

Here's the result, using an ordinary Torus.  Notice that you can still see the seams but they're more obscure.  On your fat torus they'll be even more so.

[image: Final result]

Answer (score 1):

Go into the node editor and see if your texture has this kind of projection. If so you can turn up the "Blend" value to blur the edges, or you can switch it from "Box" to "Sphere" and see if that fixes it. Otherwise it probably has something to do with UVs, but seeing as it's a procedural mesh I don't think that's it.

[image]

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/SVH9ADk this is what the nodes look like, switching them to box or sphere and changing the blend value did not fix it, unless I did something wrong.